# create function that will accept multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to modify my function to accept a different number of arguments, so for example the arguments could be (poly1, poly2) or (poly1, poly2, poly3) and so on.

The problem I have is that I'm not sure how to increment the variable name

How can I turn the function below into a function that will accept a number of different arguments and loop through them. I would prefer a functional way to do this rather than using a for loop if possible

```
function UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(poly1, poly2, poly3, poly4) {
    var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();

    wicket.fromObject(poly1);
    var wkt1 = wicket.write();

    wicket.fromObject(poly2);
    var wkt2 = wicket.write();

    wicket.fromObject(poly3);
    var wkt3 = wicket.write();

    wicket.fromObject(poly4);
    var wkt4 = wicket.write();

   return [wkt1, wkt2, wkt3, wkt4];
}
```

My attempt

```
function UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(...args) {
  args.map(item, i => {
    wicket.fromObject(`poly${i}`);
    var wkt + i = wicket.write();
  })
```

Comment: So, Tom, does either answer answer your question?

Comment: yes your implementation is what I was after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.
You just needed to return the result from `.write()`, and return the array resulting from `.map()`.
You were also missing the `new Wkt.Wkt();` call:

```
function UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(...args) {
  var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt(); // this was missing

  return args.map(item => {   // return this. Also, the `i` isn't necessary.
    wicket.fromObject(item);  // pass `item` here.
    return wicket.write();    // return instead of variable assignment
  });
}
```